# How can I initialize and access this structure in C language?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, malloc, typedef

How can I properly access this structure and initialize `count` to 0?

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct ArrayList {
    ElemType collection[MAX];
    int count; //tracks number of elements present in List
} *ArrayList;
```

and my function is

```
void initArrayList(ArrayList *AL)
```

I tried `(*AL)->count = 0;` but I get runtime error. Please help!!

Comment: Please don't hide pointer types behind type-aliases, it will make the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: As for your problem, please create a [mcve] to show us. How do you call the function, with what arguments and variables? And are your pointers really pointing to something? What does the rest of the `initArrayList` function look like?

Comment: Please show how are you calling `initArrayList` function.

Comment: I'm calling initArrayList by calling declaring ```ArrayList AL``` in main then calling the function by ```initArrayList(&AL)```.

Comment: @DomAbejar in that case `AL` is a pointer which you cannot dereference unless making it point to valid memory.

Comment: @kiran okay thank you

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is a very bad idea to use such a typedef

```
typedef struct ArrayList {
ElemType collection[MAX];
   int count; //tracks number of elements present in List
}*ArrayList;
```

because it only confuses readers. The name `ArrayList` is used for the structure tag and for the pointer to the structure.

It would be much better to define the typedef like

```
typedef struct ArrayList{
ElemType collection[MAX];
   int count; //tracks number of elements present in List
} ArrayList;
```

Nevertheless in main write for example

```
ArrayList al = NULL;

initArrayList( &al );
```

and within the function

```
*al = malloc( sizeof( **al ) );
( *al )->count = 0;
```

Comment: Once again hiding pointer types behind a type-alias bites someone. `ArrayList` is a `struct ArrayList *`, so `(*al)->count = 0` would be correct.

Comment: Also accessing `ArrayList al;` is undefined behavior as it is not initialized to memory.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that ```(*al)->count = 0``` is correct but I don't know why I get runtime error zzz

Comment: @kiranBiradar There is neither undefined behavior, Do not confuse readers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why do you say so? `al` is declared as  pointer to `struct ArrayList`.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I did not see that the typedef declares a pointer.:)